# Probability of selected two similar candy from a bowl containing 5 candies

Tags: probability

A bowl containing a two lemon candies, a grape and two cherry candies. What are all the ways two candies be selected.

What is the probability two similar flavoured candies be selected.

What is the probability a grape and a lemon flavored candy is selected

Answer (score 0):

I think it is clear that there are not so many ways to select two candies.

$L: Lemon \quad(1,2)\\
C:  Cherry \quad(3,4)\\
G:  Grape \quad \phantom{00}(5)$

These are all the ways
$LL,CC,LC,LG,CG$

Not every way is equally likely!  Why?

If you were to number the candies, so that each lemon has a different number, and each cherry has a different number, then there are $\pmatrix{5\\2}=10$ ways of selecting candies.

This should be enough to get started $\cdots$

$$P(\text{two similar})=P(LL)+P(CC)= \frac{\circ}{10}+\frac{\circ}{10}$$

$$P(\text{grape & lemon})= \frac{\text{number of ways to achieve }GL}{10}$$